# Time and Works:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A can built a wall in 8 days while b can destroy the same wall in 3
>   days. A start the work and worked for 6 days, during the last 2 days of
>   which B also joins him. In how many days A finish the remaining work
>   alone

I have tried :

I have formed one equation

```
6/8 - 2/3 + x =1
```

> This equation states that A works for 6 days out of 8 days and b
>   destroys the the wall so i subtracted the equation and the remaining
>   work i placed as x which is equal full part work 1

```
That equation showing wrong answer,what I am doing mistake, please guide me answer
```

**with B joins A to destroy the wall , guide me answer**

Comment: I need a small clarification here. When $b$ joins $a$, does $b$ destroy the wall, or does $b$ help $a$  build the wall? If he helps build the wall, we don't know how long it takes $b$ to build a wall (we know how long it takes for him to *destroy* it), so there is information missing.  Thank you.

Comment: when B joins with A to destroy the wall,can you suggest the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the unitary method : convert each person's work to "work per day".

$A$ makes the wall in $8$ days, so in one day, he does $\frac 18$ work.

$B$ destroys the wall in three days, so in  one day, he does $-\frac 13$ work (remember, destruction of the wall is negative work in our context).

Hence, it is mentioned that $A$ worked for six days. Four of these days he worked separately,that means he completed $4 \times \frac 18 = \frac 48$ of the work.

Then $B$ joined him. $B$ and $A$ together, would do $2\left(\frac 13 - \frac 18\right) = -\frac {10}{24}$ amount of work.

That is, at the end of six days, the total amount of work done is $\frac 48 - \frac{10}{24} = \frac{1}{12}$ (after simplification)

So the remaining work is $1-\frac{1}{12} = \frac{11}{12}$. The time taken by $A$ to do this is $\frac{11}{12} \div \frac 18 = \frac{22}{3}$ days. Hence, $A$ requires $22$ days and $16$ hours more, to finish his work.

Now, if $B$ takes $3$ days to *build* a wall rather than destroy it, then his contribution per day will be $+ \frac 13$, not $-$. I leave you to see the situation here (just tweak the suitable equation).

Answer (score 1):

Your equation should rather be:

```
6/8 - 2/3 + x/8 =1
```

It means
$$
t_1 r_a + t_2 r_b + t r_a = 1 \,\text{wall}
$$
with given times
$$
t_1 = 6 \,\text{days} \\
t_2 = 2 \,\text{days} \\
$$
unknown time $t$
and rates
$$
r_a = \frac{1 \,\text{wall}}{8\,\text{days}} \\
r_b = - \frac{1 \,\text{wall}}{3\,\text{days}} \\
$$

Comment: please upvote my question @mvw, thank you for guiding